# Filter doc if a specified multivalued filed contains only one value

Tags: solr

We encounter a query case that to filter doc if a specified multivalued filed contains only one value.
For instance:
We have an index of suit, including clothes ,trousers or other things. If there is only one product within a suit due to out of stock, we can't show the suit to user, because it's not 'suit'.
Here is our data:

```
<doc>
    <int name="suitId">001</int>
    <arr name="productName">
        <str>T-shirt</str>
        <str>jeans</str>
    </arr>
</doc>
<doc>
    <int name="suitId">002</int>
    <arr name="productName">
        <str>T-shirt</str>
    </arr>
</doc>
```

We wanna except the suit of suitId=002.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to have a separate field maintaining the count of the products for a suit and use it to filter the suits.

I don't think you can use the range queries for the text multivalued fields.
you can probably use `productName:[* TO *]` to select suit having atleast one product, but not the count.